# Compilation error when size of Array of user defined class is long type

Tags: java

when i working on java ,i tried to create an array of Node class . For specifying size i used int before,it worked fine but when i changed to long it is giving me compilation error. plz check the code below.

```
public class Simple {
    long maxsize = 7657567579l; // it fails when i tried to use value out-of-range of int
    Node[] nudes = new Node[maxsize];

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Simple simple = new Simple();
    }
}

class Node {
    public Object data;
    public long next;

    public Node(Object data, long next) {
        super();
        this.data = data;
        this.next = next;
    }

    public Object getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(Object data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public long getNext() {
        return next;
    }

    public void setNext(int next) {
        this.next = next;
    }

}
```

Comment: Array accept only positive integer argument...!
Even max of integer can cause an exception.

Comment: Why do you want to create an array of 7657567579 Node instances? Your computer doesn't have enough memory to hold such a big array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the documentation for array creation on below link

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.10

> > Each dimension expression undergoes unary numeric promotion. The promoted type must be int, or a compile-time error occurs.

So using `short`, `byte`, `char` and `int` should work fine, both at compile time and run-time.

As expected, `int` can be promoted to `long` and not the other way around, you are getting compile time error in your code

Answer (score 2):

Because that constructor takes an `int` argument? What do you expect to happen other than a compilation error? It's funny that you can not create

```
array[Integer.MAX_VALUE]
```

but you can:

```
array[Integer.MAX_VALUE - 4]
```

Or even 10 of these last declared arrays, almost 10x times more than the one you can't.

Comment: It takes an argument that can be promoted to `int`, say `short` or `byte` for example